# Constable of the river book

Tags: story-identification, novel

This is yet another by me where I only recall a snippet of the main story, but hopefully it'll jog someone's memory.

In the 1990s I read a space opera story, I don't recall very much of the story, I **think** a girl is on the run and gets temporary refuge from a police constable. (Or maybe not and no girl!)

This is the key part I recall

The constable had a longish section of a river to patrol, using only a small rowboat, on another planet. He was humanoid but **perhaps** had tusks.
He knew that one day his son(s) would assassinate him and take his job, that's the way things are done amongst his people.

And that's really all I've got!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Child of the River](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/428743.Child_of_the_River), the first book of the Confluence trilogy by Paul McAuley. It starts:

> The Constable of Aeolis was a shrewd, pragmatic man who did not believe in miracles. In his opinion, everything must have an explanation, and simple explanations were best of all. "The sharpest knife cuts cleanest," he often told his sons. "The more a man talks, the more likely it is he's lying." But to the end of his days, he could not explain the affair of the white boat.

And as you say he does have tusks:

> The Constable was drinking steadily from a cruse of wine. He was a large man with loose gray skin and gross features, like a figure hastily molded from clay and abandoned before it was completed. A pair of tusks protruded like daggers from his meaty upper lip. One tusk had been broken when he had fought and killed his father, and the Constable had had capped with silver; silver chinked against the neck of the cruse each time he took a swig of wine.

He finds the baby on the white boat, but it's a boy (called *Yama*) not a girl:

> The Constable squinted through the light, saw something move within it, and reached out. For a moment he was at the incandescent heart of the machines' intricate dance, and then they were gone, dispersing in flat trajectories into the darkness. The baby, a boy, pale and fat and hairless, squirmed in the Constable's hands.

The bit about his sons assassinating him is:

> the Constable knew that he could not rely on good luck forever. He was getting old, ponderous and muddled when once he had been quick and strong. He knew that sooner or later one of his sons would challenge him, and he was worried that this night's botched episode was a harbinger of his decline. Like all strong men, he feared his own weakness more than death, for strength was how he measured the worth of his life.

This one I didn't even have to Google. For some reason the book has left an imprint on me that remains twenty years after I read it. It has a strange exoticism to it that struck me very forcefully. The fact you can remember the details of the *Constable* so clearly suggest I am not alone in this.

Comment: Cheers, now to download for a re-read